# Regular expression matching words between N and M characters and containing a fixed substring

Tags: c#, regex

I need regex for words that meet both conditions:

1. contain a substring (eg foo): `\b\w*foo\w*\b`
2. fixed number of characters `\b\w{N,M}\b`

How to unify the two conditions?

If N and M are smalls is possible using OR.

N = 4 and M = 5

```
(\bfoo\w{1,2}\b)|(\b\wfoo\w{0,1}\b)|(\b\w\wfoo\b)
```

But this method is horrible for eg. N = 4, M = 20

Answer (score 3):

To "and" multiple patterns, you can use zero-width lookaheads. I don't know if these are supported in C#. In Perl, it would look like:

```
/
    \b
    (?= \w{N,M} \b )
    (?= \w* foo \w* \b )
/x
```

or

```
/
    \b
    (?= \w{N,M} \b )
    \w* foo \w* \b
/x
```

or

```
/
    \b
    (?= \w{N,M} \b )
    \w* foo
/x
```

It's usually better not to jam everything into one pattern, though. I would write

```
my @words = /\b\w{N,M}\b/g;  # Find what we define to be words.
grep /foo/, @words           # Check if any of them are acceptable to us.
```

(Sorry, that's Perl again, but I don't know C#. Just trying to give ideas.)

Comment: not work. Lookahead is not for that. foo(?=abc) match with "foo" ONLY ifit is followed by "abc"

Comment: @renegm, I didn't use `foo(?=abc)`. Give me an example that doesn't work.

Comment: Everywhere. You write: \b(?=\w{N,M}\b) etc. That match with \b if is followed by \w{N,M}. I have perl too. Test yourself.

Comment: @renegm, Yes, and that's what you want. `\w{N,M}` is suppose to come after `\b`, so you just said my code does what it should do. Again, please give an example where my expression doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. The first and third do not work. The second does. I made ​​a mistake in copying it (extra space) This works \b(?=\w{N,M}\b)\w*foo\w*\b

Comment: The first regex works in the sense of *finding* the words, it just doesn't *consume* them.  Check out this **[demo](http://ideone.com/KNhnf)** and you'll see the starting index of each match is correct.  The third regex consumes the word, just not necessarily the *whole* word.  So they both work, but they're both kinda pointless.  But +1 for the second regex, which is both correct *and* useful. ;)

Comment: @Alan Moore, All three of my match operators match the same strings, and all three can be used to extract the same data from the string, so it's not true that two are pointless. The second simply has the additional feature that the pattern it uses can be used inside of another pattern, but that doesn't make the other two wrong. Now, the OP appears to want that feature, but he gave no hint of needing that originally.

Comment: @Alan Moore, OHHHH, I get it, you guys don't know how to extract subpatterns in C#, or C# isn't capable of doing that (which would really suck). That's not a problem with what I posted. If I wanted to capture the word in Perl, I would simply place capturing parens around `\w{N,M}`.

Comment: Yes, I know how about capturing groups, and so does C#. ;)  But different languages tend to encourage different approaches to things, as I'm sure you're aware.  Consider this **[demo](http://ideone.com/4ZqV1)**.  The output is the same for both approaches, but to a C# programmer, the first seems more sensible.  The regex in the second approach takes a little more effort to understand, and of course there's the added effort of referencing the capturing group.

Comment: @Alan Moore, Perl just returns a boolean unless you have captures. It's faster that way (given Perl's simpler syntax) since one rarely care how the pattern matches, just if it matches.

Comment: And if you do want to retrieve the group captures, you perform the match in list context and then you can assign each capture to its own variable, ignoring the full match (e.g. `my ($word) = $s =~ /\b(?=(\w{6,14}\b))\w*FOO/g;` - and see yet another **[demo](http://ideone.com/nlv6b)**).  In C# you always have to access them via Match objects.  It's still easy enough, but the full-match "path" offers noticeably less resistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the wisest in this case is to not to join both regexes. Just do two regex searches, or first find words that meet one of the regexes, and then search the other regex for each word you find. At first sight, it doesn't seem easy to specify how many elements would be before and after `foo` with the `{}` syntax.

Comment: The lookaheads would tehcnically do what you want, but I think this is a better solution to the problem at hand.